# how to make a contact email form with a dropdown menu that is linked to 3 emails

Tags: email, contact-form

Hey i want to create a contact form that has a dropdown menu and depending on which of the 3 choices you pick the form will be sent to a different email. I don't know if this is even possible but any help will be greatly appreciated

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <p class="contact-form-sender">
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p class="contact-form-email">
    <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
    </p>
    <p class="contact-form-subject">
    <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" />
    </p>

    <p class="contact-form-content">
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="Your enquiries" name="message"></textarea>
    </p>

    <span class="button-met light"><input id="consubmit" type="submit" name="consubmit" value="Send" /></span>
</form>
<?php 
$toemail = 'email@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
if(mail($toemail, $subject , $message, 'From: ' . $email)) {
    echo 'Your email was sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'There was a problem sending your email.';
}
?>
```

is the code that im am using for the form

Comment: Yes, this is very possible.  The question is, what attempt are you making toward this goal?  We'll be happy to help with any implementation details you have, but we're certainly not going to just build it for you.

Comment: i know how to create the form and what not. what i dont understand is how i could change which email is picked to send the email to by selecting one of the dropdown items. the php code i have is                                <?php 
$toemail = 'myemail';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
if(mail($toemail, $subject , $message, 'From: ' . $email)) {
 echo 'Your email was sent successfully.';
} else {
 echo 'There was a problem sending your email.';
}
?>

Comment: Please include code (formatted) in the question, not in comments.  It's very difficult to read code in comments.  Once thing I notice in the code, though, is that you're setting `$toemail` to a hard-coded value.  It sounds like you want to set it to a value from the form.  You're already doing that for other variables and form values, why not also do it for the `select` value?

Comment: i just changed it cause it had my email, so i had just put myemail as a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Notice where you're using form values:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

And where you're not using a form value:

```
$toemail = 'email@gmail.com';
```

In order to make the "to" address dynamic by a form element, just add a form element for it and use it in place of the hard-coded email address.  So you can add a `select` to the form, something like this:

```
<select name="toAddress">
    <option value="email1@address.com">email1@address.com</option>
    <option value="email2@address.com">email2@address.com</option>
    <option value="email3@address.com">email3@address.com</option>
</select>
```

(Naturally, you'll want to use the actual email addresses in question.)

Then in your code you would use the form value:

```
$toemail = $_POST['toAddress'];
```